# Simplify Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, apache-kafka

I am writing a GenericDeserializer for Apache Kafka. My class implements `IDeserializer<T>` from `Confluent.Kafka.Net` package. I need to supply a Deserialize method which has this signature, `T Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, bool isNull, SerializationContext context)`. But I also need to use `Deserializers` class of Confluent because it implements some low level details such as decoding a big endian message from network as primitive types, as byte array, as UTF8 string etc. How can I simplify this method. One example of simplification may be removing the use of casts which I introduced to make the compiler happy.

My logic in this method is like this, use every supported type in already implemented `Deserializers` class. For other types that are not deserialized with the help of this class, use Json Serialization. Here is my code:

```
public class GenericDeserializer<T> : IDeserializer<T>
{
    public T Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, bool isNull, SerializationContext context)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (type == typeof(double))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.Double.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal;
        }
        if (type == typeof(float))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.Single.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal; 
        }
        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.Int32.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal; 
        }
        if (type == typeof(long))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.Int64.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal; 
        }
        if (type == typeof(Null))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.Null.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal; 
        }
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.Utf8.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal; 
        }
        if (type == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            var retVal = Deserializers.ByteArray.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);

            return (T) (object) retVal; 
        }
        if (isNull)
        {
            return default;
        }
        
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data, new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the source of `Deserializers` class from `Confluent.Kafka`
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Deserializers.cs

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettypecode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @RickDavin We can handle simple primitive types with `GetTypeCode`. But how do we handle the types such as `byte[]` or `Null` (a type in Confluent library).

Comment: I don't think it's a particularly good idea to deliver `default`of a struct if the method has been told that you should deserialize to `null`. You should instead be deserializing to `double?`, `long?`, etc., and not using `default`.

Comment: @Reinderien We cannot make a `Nullable<T>` type if `T` is not a ValueType, we have to introduce a struct constraint but that breaks generic method.

Comment: Right; I'm not saying to return `Nullable<T>` when `T` is a struct; I'm saying that you shouldn't accept `T` as a struct at all. This can be enforced on generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a mapping between `Type`s and the `Deserializers`. You can do this for example like this:

```cs
public class GenericDeserializer<T> : IDeserializer<T>
{
    private readonly ImmutableDictionary<Type, object> _deserializers =
        new Dictionary<Type, object>
    {
        { typeof(double), Deserializers.Double },
        { typeof(float), Deserializers.Single },
        { typeof(int), Deserializers.Int32 },
        { typeof(long), Deserializers.Int64 },
        { typeof(Null), Deserializers.Null },
        { typeof(string), Deserializers.Utf8 },
        { typeof(byte[]), Deserializers.ByteArray },
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();
}
```

You can't use the `IDeserializer<T>` in the Dictionary's Value type parameter that's why it is an `object`.

Then all you need to do is to make a lookup call and try to cast the value to `IDeserializer<T>`

```cs
if (_deserializers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
{
    var deserializer = _deserializers[typeof(T)] as IDeserializer<T>;
    ...
}
```

If the type was found then you can make branching based on the `isNull` value:

```cs
if (_deserializers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
{
    var deserializer = _deserializers[typeof(T)] as IDeserializer<T>;
    var retVal = deserializer.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);
    return !isNull ? retVal : default;
}
```

If it is not found then you can use the `JsonSerializer` as your fallback.

```cs
return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data, new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
```

---

The final code would look like this:

```cs
public class GenericDeserializer<T> : IDeserializer<T>
{
    private readonly ImmutableDictionary<Type, object> _deserializers =
        new Dictionary<Type, object>
    {
        { typeof(double), Deserializers.Double },
        { typeof(float), Deserializers.Single },
        { typeof(int), Deserializers.Int32 },
        { typeof(long), Deserializers.Int64 },
        { typeof(Null), Deserializers.Null },
        { typeof(string), Deserializers.Utf8 },
        { typeof(byte[]), Deserializers.ByteArray },
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();

    public T Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, bool isNull, SerializationContext context)
    {
        if (_deserializers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            var deserializer = _deserializers[typeof(T)] as IDeserializer<T>;
            var retVal = deserializer.Deserialize(data, isNull, context);
            return !isNull ? retVal : default;
        }

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data, new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but if `typeof(T)` does not exist in dictionary and it will throw `KeyNotFoundException`, am I wrong?

Comment: @ndogac Yepp, you are right, I've just amended my answer to overcome on this issue.

Comment: `TryGetValue` is better than `ContainsKey` because you can lookup through dictionary once instead of twice. Also `JsonSerializerOptions` can be static/single instance/lazy. Also the logic is different from the initial code. @ndogac, fyi

Comment: @aepot Yes, it can be further optimized. I just wanted to share the core idea to avoid code duplication (calling the Deserialize method), you can use mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the branching in the `Deserialize` method and instead move that logic to a place that is executed only once - the construction place. An instance of your `GenericDeserializer<T>` will always execute the same branch for any input, because the instance is already tied to a specific output type T. For the types like int, and double where you use their implementation just return their implementation, use your implementation for the rest.

```
class JsonDeserializer<T> : IDeserializer<T>
{
    public T Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, bool isNull, SerializationContext context)
    {
        if (isNull)
        {
            return default;
        }
        
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data, new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });
    }
}


IDeserializer<T> CreateDeserializer<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (type == typeof(double))
    {
        return (IDeserializer<T>) Deserializers.Double;
    }

    if (type === typeof(long))
    {
        return (IDeserializer<T>) Deserializers.Int64;
    }

    // ...

    return new JsonDeserializer<T>();
}
```

Comment: This way, we do not get rid of branching, but move it into `CreateDeserializer<T>` method. There is also redundancy in writing deserializers for every supported type, we do not actually need these classes because we can return `Deserializers.Double` directly.

Comment: @ndogac aha, i didnt know they already implement the interface, And it didn't make sense to me why wouldnt you return them directly if they did. And that's exactly what i suggest you do then...

Comment: And sry, i didnt imply you use the CreateDeserializer<T> as Is. It was just an example of a calling code. I meant you get rid of the branching everytime the Deserialize method Is called.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot return `Deserializers.Double` for example, if the return type is `IDeserializer<T>` and we are returning `IDeserializer<double>`, the cast will be required again and we have the same readability problem.

Comment: In the updated code example, I get *DoubleDeserializer is not assignable to IDeserializer<T>* error.

Comment: @ndogac Well, I'm sorry. I don't work with C# too often. I didn't realize the cast is needed in C#. I have rewritten my answer to target just the aspect of executing the branching only once.